# Web scraping in Investing.com with Excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I have no knowledge of vba. Only the macro recorder is used.
I need to download the data from a web page to an Excel spreadsheet and with my knowledge of vba I am not capable.

In particular, what I want to do a macro to download to Excel a data table of the page: https://www.investing.com/equities/cellnex-telecom-historical-data

This download would have to be configured in terms of time, date range and ordering.

The steps would be the following:
1.- The objective is to copy the data from the "CLNX historical data" table to an Excel spreadsheet.
2.- That download should be done by previously selecting "Monthly" in the drop-down menu by calling "Term".
3.- That the download is made by previously selecting the range of dates for the last 2 years.
4.- Finally, order the table in descending order by the column "Maximum".
5.- Once the term, the date range and the order are selected, copy the data from the "CLNX historical data" table to an Excel spreadsheet.

I have tried with the macro recorder but I am not able to configure the term, the date range or the ordering.

Could someone help me?

Thanks for your help.

The code:

```
Sub DataInvesting()

Dim IE As Object

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

IE.navigate "https://www.investing.com/equities/cellnex-telecom-historical-data"

Do Until IE.readyState = 4

DoEvents

Loop

IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("newInput selectBox float_lang_base_1")(0).Value = "Monthly"

IE.Visible = True

Set IE = Nothing

Set appIE = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Share the code you have and explain what isn't working. Limit to one question per post I would suggest.

Comment: Sub DataInvesting()

Dim IE As Object

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

IE.navigate "https://es.investing.com/equities/acs-cons-y-serv-historical-data"

Do Until IE.readyState = 4

DoEvents

Loop

IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("newInput selectBox float_lang_base_1")(0).Value = "Monthly"

IE.Visible = True

Set IE = Nothing

Set appIE = Nothing

End Sub

Comment: Maximum what? Change (last column?) And is term a dropdown option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have just tested the following code and it works, instead of creating an instance of internet explorer every time we need to run this macro, we will use xmlhttp requests. Just copy the entire code and paste it into a module in vba. Don't forget to add references (Tools/References) to Microsoft HTML Object Library and Microsoft XML v6.0.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Export_Table()

'Html Objects---------------------------------------'
 Dim htmlDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
 Dim htmlBody As MSHTML.htmlBody
 Dim ieTable As MSHTML.HTMLTable
 Dim Element As MSHTML.HTMLElementCollection


'Workbooks, Worksheets, Ranges, LastRow, Incrementers ----------------'
 Dim wb As Workbook
 Dim Table As Worksheet
 Dim i As Long

 Set wb = ThisWorkbook
 Set Table = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

 '-------------------------------------------'
 Dim xmlHttpRequest As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60  '
 '-------------------------------------------'


 i = 2

'Web Request --------------------------------------------------------------------------'
 With xmlHttpRequest
 .Open "POST", "https://www.investing.com/instruments/HistoricalDataAjax", False
.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
.setRequestHeader "X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest"
.send "curr_id=951681&smlID=1695217&header=CLNX+Historical+Data&st_date=01%2F01%2F2017&end_date=03%2F01%2F2019&interval_sec=Monthly&sort_col=date&sort_ord=DESC&action=historical_data"


 If .Status = 200 Then

        Set htmlDoc = CreateHTMLDoc
        Set htmlBody = htmlDoc.body

        htmlBody.innerHTML = xmlHttpRequest.responseText

        Set ieTable = htmlDoc.getElementById("curr_table")

        For Each Element In ieTable.getElementsByTagName("tr")
            Table.Cells(i, 1) = Element.Children(0).innerText
            Table.Cells(i, 2) = Element.Children(1).innerText
            Table.Cells(i, 3) = Element.Children(2).innerText
            Table.Cells(i, 4) = Element.Children(3).innerText
            Table.Cells(i, 5) = Element.Children(4).innerText
            Table.Cells(i, 6) = Element.Children(5).innerText
            Table.Cells(i, 7) = Element.Children(6).innerText

            i = i + 1
        DoEvents: Next Element
 End If
End With


Set xmlHttpRequest = Nothing
Set htmlDoc = Nothing
Set htmlBody = Nothing
Set ieTable = Nothing
Set Element = Nothing

End Sub

Public Function CreateHTMLDoc() As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Set CreateHTMLDoc = CreateObject("htmlfile")
End Function
```

Comment: This does the full 2 years in monthly intervals and sorted?

Comment: i edited the code to fit you, just the column of data you should format as text in excel, so give it a try.

Comment: that looks better! I wil have a go with it Though not sure about having an entire function whose sole purpose is to generate a late bound html file which is passed back as an early bound .

Comment: Nice though would probably help OP if you included urlencoding  part rather than using already encoded so they can pass it alternate parameters. Also, your writing out can be done with a single loop if you use For Loop to .Length -1 (would reduce code lines). +1 btw   This is inefficient: Set ieTable = htmlDoc.all.Item("curr_table"), can you grab by id?

Comment: Yes, it can be grabbed by ID, just tested. But anyway has no impact in speed, as for the loop i think is more clean like this and it is a single loop. I don't get the part where you say "to include urlencoding part rather than using already encoded so they can pass alternate parameters", can you explain more i'm interested.

Comment: The point about id is best practice as to some extent is the refactoring of the loop. It is cleaner to not repeat lines unnecessarily. But, it is your answer! The urlencoding bit is that this: "curr_id=951681&smlID=1695217&header=CLNX+Historical+Data&st_date=01%2F01%2F2017&end_date=03%2F01%2F2019&interval_sec=Monthly&sort_col=date&sort_ord=DESC&action=historical_data   is encoded (the dates parameters), presumably taken from dev tools where browser has taken care of spaces etc. You can use encodeUrl function to do the same thing.

Comment: you are right, i will give it a try about urlencode. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I can't test this as despite setting up a free account it keeps saying the password is wrong. Fed up with 5 password resets and same problem and suspect it want my social media details.

The following broadly outlines steps I would consider though some timed waits are most likely needed.

```
Option Explicit
'VBE > Tools > References:
' Microsoft Internet Controls
Public Sub Info()
    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer  
    Const URL As String  = ""https://www.investing.com/equities/cellnex-telecom-historical-data""
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 URL

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        .document.querySelector(".login").Click

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        .Navigate2 URL

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend


        With .document.querySelector("#loginFormUser_email")
            .Focus
            .Value = "Bob@gmail.com"
        End With
        With .document.querySelector("#loginForm_password")
            .Focus
            .Value = "systemSucksDoesn'tAcceptMyPassword"
        End With

        Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 2)

        .document.querySelector("[onclick*=submitLogin]").Click

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        .document.querySelector("#data_interval").Click
        .document.querySelector("[value=Monthly]").Click
        With .document.querySelector("#picker")
            .Focus
            .Value = "03/08/2017 - 03/08/2019"
            .FireEvent "onchange"
        End With

        'TODO Sorting column when clarified which column
        .document.querySelector("[title='Download Data']").Click

        Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 10)

        Stop
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Sub Web_Table_Option()
    Dim HTMLDoc As New HTMLDocument
    Dim objTable As Object
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim lngTable As Long
    Dim lngRow As Long
    Dim lngCol As Long
    Dim ActRw As Long
    Dim objIE As InternetExplorer
    Set objIE = New InternetExplorer
    objIE.Navigate "https://www.investing.com/equities/cellnex-telecom-historical-data"

    Do Until objIE.ReadyState = 4 And Not objIE.Busy
        DoEvents
    Loop
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03")) 'wait for java script to load
    HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = objIE.Document.body.innerHTML
    With HTMLDoc.body
        Set objTable = .getElementsByTagName("curr_table")
        For lngTable = 0 To objTable.Length - 1
            For lngRow = 0 To objTable(lngTable).Rows.Length - 1
                For lngCol = 0 To objTable(lngTable).Rows(lngRow).Cells.Length - 1
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(ActRw + lngRow + 1, lngCol + 1) = objTable(lngTable).Rows(lngRow).Cells(lngCol).innerText
                Next lngCol
            Next lngRow
            ActRw = ActRw + objTable(lngTable).Rows.Length + 1
        Next lngTable
    End With
    objIE.Quit
End Sub
```