# Web scraping in Investing.com portfolio with Excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, cryptocurrency

I am trying to scrape the cyrpto currency information in my portfolio (e.g. current worth, change% etc.). I tried to come up with a useful code in last 10 hours but couldn't do it. First I tried the very nice code in here: [Web scraping in Investing.com with Excel vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55063008/web-scraping-in-investing-com-with-excel-vba)

However, it is for getting defined table information and I am not familiar with webscraping too much, especially with XML method. So I couldn't make it work.

The page I am trying to scrape is only reachable via login; therefore, I will try to show the html via copying here and screenshots.

The page I am trying to scrape:
[image: portfolio]

You may check the example html screenshot (1061477 is id of Dogecoin) and html code below:
[image: html example]

```html
<tbody id="tbody_overview_5563889" class="ui-sortable">
        <tr id="sort_945629" rel="5563889_945629" data-pair-id="945629" data-pair-exchange-id="1014" data-is-open-by="exchange" data-is-pair-exchange-open="1">
            <td class="left dragHandle"><span class="checkers"></span></td>
        <td class="flag"><span title="" class="ceFlags bitcoin">&nbsp;</span></td>
    <td data-column-name="name" data-pair-id="945629" class="symbol plusIconTd left bold elp  alert js-injected-user-alert-container">
        <span class="aqPopupWrapper js-hover-me-wrapper"><a target="_blank" href="/crypto/bitcoin/btc-usd" title="BTC/USD - Bitcoin US Dollar" class="aqlink js-hover-me" hoverme="markets" data-pairid="945629">BTC/USD</a></span>
        <span class="js-plus-icon alertBellGrayPlus genToolTip oneliner" data-tooltip="Create Alert" data-tooltip-alt="Alert is active"></span>
    </td>
    <td data-column-name="symbol" class="left bold "><a target="_blank" href="/crypto/bitcoin/btc-usd" title=""></a></td>
    <td data-column-name="exchange" class="left displayNone" title="Bitfinex">Bitfinex</td>
    <td data-column-name="last" class="pid-945629-last" id="5563889_last_945629">40,324.0</td>
    <td data-column-name="bid" class="pid-945629-bid displayNone" id="5563889_bid_945629">40,322.0</td>
    <td data-column-name="ask" class="pid-945629-ask displayNone" id="5563889_ask_945629">40,323.0</td>
    <td data-column-name="extended_hours" class="js-extended-hours js-extended-last Font pidExt-945629-last displayNone">--</td>
    <td data-column-name="extended_hours_percent" class="js-extended-hours js-extended-percent Font pidExt-945629-pcp displayNone">--</td>
    <td data-column-name="open" class="">37,461.0</td>
    <td data-column-name="prev" class="displayNone">37,461.0</td>
    <td data-column-name="high" class="pid-945629-high " id="5563889_high_945629">40,380.0</td>
    <td data-column-name="low" class="pid-945629-low " id="5563889_low_945629">37,233.0</td>
    <td data-column-name="chg" class="bold pid-945629-pc greenFont" id="5563889_chg_945629">+2863.0</td>
    <td data-column-name="chgpercent" class="bold pid-945629-pcp greenFont" id="5563889_p_chg_945629">+7.64%</td>
    <td data-column-name="vol" class="pid-945629-turnover " data-value="8733">8.88K</td>
    <td data-column-name="next_earning" class="left textNum displayNone" data-value="0">--</td>
    <td data-column-name="time" class="pid-945629-time " id="5563889_time_945629" data-value="1612610025">06:13:45</td>
        <td class="icon" id="5563889_isopen_945629"><span class="greenClockIcon middle isOpenExch-1014"></span></td>
        <td class="icon"><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-pair-id="945629" data-portfolio-id="5563889" rel="removePairFromPortfolio_5563889" class="bugCloseIcon genToolTip oneliner" data-tooltip="Delete">&nbsp;</a></td>
    </tr><tr id="sort_1061477" rel="5563889_1061477" data-pair-id="1061477" data-pair-exchange-id="1037" data-is-open-by="exchange" data-is-pair-exchange-open="1">
            <td class="left dragHandle"><span class="checkers"></span></td>
        <td class="flag"><span title="" class="ceFlags dogecoin">&nbsp;</span></td>
    <td data-column-name="name" data-pair-id="1061477" class="symbol plusIconTd left bold elp  alert js-injected-user-alert-container">
        <span class="aqPopupWrapper js-hover-me-wrapper"><a target="_blank" href="/indices/investing.com-doge-usd" title="Investing.com Dogecoin Index" class="aqlink js-hover-me" hoverme="markets" data-pairid="1061477">Dogecoin</a></span>
        <span class="js-plus-icon alertBellGrayPlus genToolTip oneliner" data-tooltip="Create Alert" data-tooltip-alt="Alert is active"></span>
    </td>
    <td data-column-name="symbol" class="left bold "><a target="_blank" href="/indices/investing.com-doge-usd" title="DOGE/USD">DOGE/USD</a></td>
    <td data-column-name="exchange" class="left displayNone" title="Investing.com">Investing.com</td>
    <td data-column-name="last" class="pid-1061477-last" id="5563889_last_1061477">0.048506</td>
    <td data-column-name="bid" class=" displayNone" id="5563889_bid_1061477">-</td>
    <td data-column-name="ask" class=" displayNone" id="5563889_ask_1061477">-</td>
    <td data-column-name="extended_hours" class="js-extended-hours js-extended-last Font pidExt-1061477-last displayNone">--</td>
    <td data-column-name="extended_hours_percent" class="js-extended-hours js-extended-percent Font pidExt-1061477-pcp displayNone">--</td>
    <td data-column-name="open" class="">0.043969</td>
    <td data-column-name="prev" class="displayNone">0.043969</td>
    <td data-column-name="high" class="pid-1061477-high " id="5563889_high_1061477">0.051038</td>
    <td data-column-name="low" class="pid-1061477-low " id="5563889_low_1061477">0.044505</td>
    <td data-column-name="chg" class="bold pid-1061477-pc greenFont" id="5563889_chg_1061477">+0.004537</td>
    <td data-column-name="chgpercent" class="bold pid-1061477-pcp greenFont" id="5563889_p_chg_1061477">+10.32%</td>
    <td data-column-name="vol" class="pid-1061477-turnover " data-value="21137638982">21.08B</td>
    <td data-column-name="next_earning" class="left textNum displayNone" data-value="0">--</td>
    <td data-column-name="time" class="pid-1061477-time " id="5563889_time_1061477" data-value="1612610031">06:13:51</td>
        <td class="icon" id="5563889_isopen_1061477"><span class="greenClockIcon middle isOpenExch-1037"></span></td>
        <td class="icon"><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-pair-id="1061477" data-portfolio-id="5563889" rel="removePairFromPortfolio_5563889" class="bugCloseIcon genToolTip oneliner" data-tooltip="Delete">&nbsp;</a></td>
    </tr><tr id="sort_1057392" rel="5563889_1057392" data-pair-id="1057392" data-pair-exchange-id="1037" data-is-open-by="exchange" data-is-pair-exchange-open="1">
            <td class="left dragHandle"><span class="checkers"></span></td>
        <td class="flag"><span title="" class="ceFlags ripple">&nbsp;</span></td>
    <td data-column-name="name" data-pair-id="1057392" class="symbol plusIconTd left bold elp  alert js-injected-user-alert-container">
        <span class="aqPopupWrapper js-hover-me-wrapper"><a target="_blank" href="/indices/investing.com-xrp-usd" title="Investing.com XRP Index" class="aqlink js-hover-me" hoverme="markets" data-pairid="1057392">XRP</a></span>
        <span class="js-plus-icon alertBellGrayPlus genToolTip oneliner" data-tooltip="Create Alert" data-tooltip-alt="Alert is active"></span>
    </td>
```

I highlighted the parts that I am trying to get.

Although it is too slow, I was able to scrape some of the data with below code (x=1061477). I am getting error on redfont ones since it becomes green when the currency is going up. I tried to use the ID, but couldn't get the data. Also it changes my computer's time somehow :)

```
Sub getprice()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Dim text As String
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim sht As Worksheet

Set sht = ActiveSheet
lastrow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastrow

x = Cells(i, 1).Value


Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    
    IE.navigate "https://www.investing.com/portfolio/?portfolioID=NTUwZjJiZjkzbT46NW8%3D"
    Do While IE.Busy And IE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
    Sleep 500
    Dim last As String
    'Name = .document.getElementsByClassName("aqPopupWrapper js-hover-me-wrapper")(0).outerText
    last = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("pid-" & x & "-last")(0).outerText
    high = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("pid-" & x & "-high")(0).outerText
    low = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("pid-" & x & "-low")(0).outerText
    'Change = IE.document.getElementById("5563889_chg_1057392")(0).innerHTML
    Change = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("bold pid-" & x & "-pc redFont")(0).outerText
    change2 = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("bold pid-" & x & "-pcp redFont")(0).outerText
    volume = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("pid-" & x & "-turnover")(0).outerText
    Time = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("pid-" & x & "-time")(0).outerText
    IE.Quit

'   ws.Cells(2, 1).Value = Name
    ws.Cells(i, 3).Value = last
    ws.Cells(i, 4).Value = high
    ws.Cells(i, 5).Value = low
    ws.Cells(i, 6).Value = Change
    ws.Cells(i, 7).Value = change2
    ws.Cells(i, 8).Value = volume
    ws.Cells(i, 9).Value = Time

Next i
End Sub
```

Any idea on how to scrape this data? Especially with XML method.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Please use the snippet tool via [edit] to insert html rather than posting pictures. Instructions here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting . You want the <> icon or Ctrl + M

Comment: I would look for an API serving this data and stick with VBA or consider using a dedicated package in another language e.g. https://investpy.readthedocs.io/

Comment: @QHarr, thanks for your comment. I added the html document. I think this should be a simple scrap. I feel like I am just missing something. For example, if I could get the elements by id="5563889_chg_1061477 instead of class, that will solve my problem as well. But getting it as a full table like the link I shared, that would be perfect.

Comment: I checked the investspy but it is for historical data. The link I shared also can get that but I need the live data from my portfolio.

Comment: ok... did the answer below throw an error?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean in comments about whole table like in shared link but the whole table as per your image should be possible. You only show HTML from the tbody level (better would have been from table tag level); however, I reconstruct a table from that HTML, by matching on start substring of the id of the tbody, pulling out the outerHTML, adding wrapping table tags, and passing that html to the clipboard to then paste to sheet.

Technically, I could easily have generated a table object and grabbed `.Rows(2).outHTML` (assuming the "japanese dog" coin is in row 2) and wrapped in `table` tags instead, just to get the one row of interest.

NOTE: NOT TESTED

```
Dim s As String

s = "<table>" & ie.document.querySelector("[id^='tbody_overview]").outerHTML & "</table>"
' s = "<table>" & ie.document.querySelector("[id^='tbody_overview]").rows(2).outerHTML & "</table>"

Dim clipboard As Object
Set clipboard = GetObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
clipboard.SetText s
clipboard.PutInClipboard
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial
```

Comment: Hello Qharr, thanks for the answer. I do not understand where and how should I use this code? I can provide the full html if that would help

Comment: For the first url the code above would go after `Do While IE.Busy And IE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop`

Answer (score 0):

First comment is that I think that authentication to [investing.com](https://www.investing.com) may not even be needed.

[investing.com](https://www.investing.com) provides a public page for each asset (stock or crypto-coin) that you can analyze. For example, to get the dogecoin info you could use the following url:

```
https://www.investing.com/crypto/dogecoin/doge-usd
```

Second comment is that there are ways to transform an html page to an Excel sheet without coding. I did something similar using [coinmarketcap.com](https://coinmarketcap.com). See blog post [here](https://daveriskit.wordpress.com/2021/05/31/doge-altcoin-in-excel-simple/).

**The same can be done for [investing.com](https://www.investing.com):**

1. Create a local file called `dogecoin-from-investing.com.iqy` in a location you will remember. Type into the file the following:

```
WEB
1
https://www.investing.com/crypto/dogecoin/doge-usd
 
Selection=AllTables
Formatting=None
PreFormattedTextToColumns=True
ConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne=True
SingleBlockTextImport=False
DisableDateRecognition=False
DisableRedirections=False
```

2. Open Excel and create a new helper sheet in your worksheet and call it DogeCoin.
3. Navigate to `Data → Get External Data → Run Web Query…` and accept all defaults.
4. Magic! Excel did all the work for you.
   You should now have a populated helper sheet with the up-to-date data about dogecoin.
   You can use that data in any other sheet as needed. The data model does not change too often, at least until investing.com decides to change it.
5. To refresh the data, navigate to the `Data` menu and hit `Refresh All`.