# Troubleshooting VBA errors in web-scraping monthly UK bond data from investing.com

Tags: excel, xml, vba, parsing, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape monthly UK bond data from investing.com for each bond increment between 1-month and 50-years. These can be found at https://uk.investing.com/rates-bonds/uk-5-year-bond-yield-historical-data for example (changing the '5-year' part of the URL for different year/month periods.

I have very limited knowledge of XML or HTML and so I have been heavily cribbing off [@Erjon's very useful program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55063008/web-scraping-in-investing-com-with-excel-vba), but I keep running into HTML 403 errors and VBA type mismatch errors with the HTML defined names (runtime error 13).

I have tried to modify the code to pull the data to pull the 5-year bond info as follows:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Export_Table()

'Html Objects---------------------------------------'
 Dim htmlDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
 Dim htmlBody As MSHTML.htmlBody
 Dim ieTable As MSHTML.HTMLTable
 Dim Element As MSHTML.HTMLTableRow


'Workbooks, Worksheets, Ranges, LastRow, Incrementers ----------------'
 Dim wb As Workbook
 Dim Table As Worksheet
 Dim i As Long

 Set wb = ThisWorkbook
 Set Table = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

 '-------------------------------------------'
 Dim xmlHttpRequest As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60  '
 '-------------------------------------------'


 i = 2

'Web Request --------------------------------------------------------------------------'
 With xmlHttpRequest
 .Open "GET", "https://uk.investing.com/rates-bonds/uk-5-year-bond-yield-historical-data", False
.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
.setRequestHeader "X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest"
.setRequestHeader "user-agent", "Chrome/99.0.4844.74"

.send "curr_id=951681&smlID=200239&st_date=01%2F01%2F2017&end_date=03%2F01%2F2019&interval_sec=Monthly&sort_col=date&sort_ord=DESC&action=historical_data"


 If .Status = 200 Then

        Set htmlDoc = CreateHTMLDoc
        Set htmlBody = htmlDoc.body

        htmlBody.innerHTML = xmlHttpRequest.responseText

        Set ieTable = htmlDoc.getElementsByClassName("datatable_table__D_jso datatable_table--border__B_zW0 datatable_table--mobile-basic__W2ilt datatable_table--freeze-column__7YoIE")

        For Each Element In ieTable.getElementsByTagName("tr")
            Table.Cells(i, 1) = Element.Children(0).innerText
            Table.Cells(i, 2) = Element.Children(1).innerText
            Table.Cells(i, 3) = Element.Children(2).innerText
            Table.Cells(i, 4) = Element.Children(3).innerText
            Table.Cells(i, 5) = Element.Children(4).innerText
            Table.Cells(i, 6) = Element.Children(5).innerText
            Table.Cells(i, 7) = Element.Children(6).innerText

            i = i + 1
        DoEvents: Next Element
 End If
End With


Set xmlHttpRequest = Nothing
Set htmlDoc = Nothing
Set htmlBody = Nothing
Set ieTable = Nothing
Set Element = Nothing

End Sub

Public Function CreateHTMLDoc() As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Set CreateHTMLDoc = CreateObject("htmlfile")
End Function
```

Currently the issue I'm facing is that I can't set the 'ieTable' variable as this is returning the runtime error 13. In Erjon's original code (as linked above), he pulls the info from "https://www.investing.com/instruments/HistoricalDataAjax", but if I try this, it keeps providing me with the HTML error

> 403: access forbidden.

If someone could please point out where I'm going wrong then that would be amazing - thank you!

Comment: Page source shows data on that page does not contain static html content as your code assumes. Especially if pulled in by ajax, data is dynamically rendered server-side.

Comment: The data is made available via a JSON. The link looks like this. https://api.investing.com/api/financialdata/historical/23668?start-date=2023-05-03&end-date=2023-06-03&time-frame=Daily&add-missing-rows=false However, permissions are necessary to access it. I don't know what these are, nor how to get them, nor how they need to be posted. I think you should look at SeleniumBasic to automate Chrome or Edge as a browser.